# How do I close an open multiple jquery.reveal.js modal boxs? (multiple popup's)

Tags: jquery, popup

check the problem what iam facing, click on the about us tab on below link after click n any other link, how can i close all the popup.

http://voyageandvacation.in/

Answer (score 2):

Try to fire a click event to the class: close-reveal-modal whe the user clicks on the home menu button or any other button which does not need a reveal-modal.

You can do that by creating a function to close all the open reveal-modal and call that on click of the Home menu button. If you use jQuery, use this:

```
$(".close-reveal-modal").trigger('click')
```